# Hidden import '.py' not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

When I use pyinstaller to package multiple python files, I meet the `"Hidden import not found"` error. The code I type in `cmd` is like this:

```
pyinstaller main.py --hidden-import SignInPage.py --hidden-import SignUpPage.py  --hidden-import ChoosePage.py --hidden-import SearchAddNumber.py
```

and the error shows:

```
56 INFO: UPX is not available.

11248 ERROR: Hidden import 'SignInPage.py' not found

11249 ERROR: Hidden import 'SignUpPage.py' not found

11250 ERROR: Hidden import 'ChoosePage.py' not found

11251 ERROR: Hidden import 'SearchAddNumber.py' not found

12900 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'
12945 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'
```

I searched online but only find that no solutions work for me. Looking forward to your answers.

---

Add some information to clearify the question.

I'm typing cmd in the file explorer. Then I use the pyinstaller command.
The file contains these things as shown in this picture:
[pyinstaller files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNfrY.png)

Comment: did you try to use `/full/path/to/SignInPage.py`, etc. OR maybe it needs name of module without `.py` ?

Comment: It would appear the files are not where pyinstaller expects to find them - this could be due to any number of reasons, it's hard to say without you providing more information or providing us with a simpler but complete example of the problem you are having.

Comment: @furas I have tired this but it doesn't work. The problem still appears in the same way. But thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Grismar I provide a new picture to help you understanding my problem. I put these .py files all in one folder, then I type "cmd" in file explorer, then I use pyinstaller, the problem appears.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not simply importing these files directly, or creating a package that contains them?